# Ensuring internal shared library versions are correct

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, shared-libraries

I'm currently tasked with trying to improve our companies versioning practices when it comes to our internal libraries.  I've read about Semantic Versioning 2.0.0 and this seems like a really nice, simple and elegant solution to our current problem where our current versioning practices (e.g. library_v01) don't really tell us much about each library version.

Ideally the applications would check the version of the library being used at compile time as to catch any mismatches before a deployment and/or test.  Our applications are written in Visual Studio and we're soon to upgrade to C++11 compiler friendly VS2013 which is why my first idea was to use static_asserts in order to check versions at compile time something like:

```
// Defined in library code and accessible by applications
struct LibraryVersion {
    static const unsigned int LIB_VERSION_MAJOR = 1;
    static const unsigned int LIB_VERSION_MINOR = 0;
    static const unsigned int LIB_VERSION_PATCH = 0;
}

// Application code
static const unsigned int EXPECTED_LIB_VERSION_MAJOR = 1;
static const unsigned int EXPECTED_LIB_VERSION_MINOR = 0;
static const unsigned int EXPECTED_LIB_VERSION_PATCH = 0;

void lib_version_check() {
    static_assert(LibraryVersion::LIB_VERSION_MAJOR == EXPECTED_LIB_VERSION_MAJOR, "Error Major");
    static_assert(LibraryVersion::LIB_VERSION_MINOR == EXPECTED_LIB_VERSION_MINOR, "Error Minor");
    static_assert(LibraryVersion::LIB_VERSION_PATCH == EXPECTED_LIB_VERSION_PATCH, "Error Patch");
}
```

Also it'd be nice to have some kind of pre-processor definition within a library prop file which could be used in include paths so that correct library files are always included by each application e.g.

```
$(LIB_DIR)="C:\Libs\"
$(LIB_VERS)="v1.0.0"
Include_Path = $(LIB_DIR)\$(LIB_VERS);
```

With the file structure looking something like:

```
C:\Libs\v1.0.0\include\...
C:\Libs\v1.0.1\include\...
C:\Libs\v1.0.2\include\...
C:\Libs\v1.2.0\include\...
```

However this to me doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution and having to keep track of two version variables (both the pre-processor value and the unsigned integers representing MAJOR, MINOR and PATCH version) seems a bit much.

So basically I'd like to ask if others have come across anything similar and if they have any insight in to what an elegant solution might be or if there are any pitfalls to using the above solution that maybe I haven't thought of?  Perhaps having a file structure like the one described above is problematic and/or there is an easier way? Any feedback would be appreciated.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just generate a header with a template using the git tags as the major, minor and patch. We do what you have done above but it's all automated. This doesn't solve the compilation dependencies.

However, the dependency of what library versions are need is hoisted up into the package dependency of our custom `waf` build system. For example:

```
# We need boost
conf.env.BOOST_MINIMUM_VERSION = (1, 50)
conf.load('boost', tooldir=vcawaflib.dir)

# VCA project dependencies
conf.env.VCA_TEST_MINIMUM_VERSION = (0, 2, 3)
conf.project_uselib('sdk/test', 'vca_test')
```

The build system interfaces with the systems package manager (on Windows it uses a custom python package manager we have written) and that resolves all the dependencies.

That being said, it has been a lot of work to get our build system set up. For your case, you could allow the compiler to work out the library dependencies but I would use `std::tuple` as that does the Right Thing when it comes to version comparisons

`include/my_awesome_library/version.h`

```
namespace my_awesome_library {
  static constexpr auto version = std::make_tuple(1, 0, 0);
}  // namespace my_awesome_library
```

`src/my_program_or_library/dependencies.c`

```
static_assert(my_awesome_library::version >= std::make_tuple(1, 0, 0), "\nmy_awesome_library is old");
```

This could be preprocessor defined as:

```
#define VERSION_CHECK(version, ...) \
  static_assert(version >= std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__), #version " is old");

VERSION_CHECK(my_awesome_library::version, 1, 0, 0);
```

You could expand it to do minimum and maximum checks, etc.

Microsoft are doing a great job of becoming more standards compliant in the newer versions Visual Studio but you'll have to check if the above works in whatever MSVC compiler you use.

Comment: Thanks for that, that looks like a pretty good solution.  How about the file structure? Would something like library\version_number\include make sense and is that something you do or is there something else obvious I haven't thought of?

Comment: Our windows package manager does the following: `third_party/prebuilt/ntlm-1.4-windows-7-x64-gcc-4.8-posix-dwarf/`. So `[library]-[version]-[os]-[release]-[arch]-[compiler]-[version]-[threading]-[exceptions]` The include folder and libraries are under that folder. MSVC looks like: `third_party/prebuilt/ntlm-1.4-windows-7-x64-msvc-10.0/`. This is because the compilers have different ABIs for each release (and exception models/threading models). Unless you make it all automatic (scripted), it'll become unmaintainable.

Comment: Yeah I can see how manual maintenance would be a problem.  So effectively (just to make sure I've grasped this correctly) a post build script is used to pull the correct version of the libraries required from a repository?

Comment: No, there is a configuration step. Much like autotools and cmake (I don't know how much you know other build systems other that Visual Studio). This resolves all of the dependencies in a shared tool chain folder. You could write a prebuild batch script to do the same, would be a monster though.

Comment: I know vaguely about them as I've touched on them whilst studying etc. but nothing at a commercial level really as its always been Visual Studio I've used.  I think I've got a much better understanding of a good versioning process now though so this should give me a good platform to work from, thanks for the help :)