# How to ensure correct version of library is loaded at run time

Tags: c++, svn

I'm developing a library (using C++) and occasionally run into the problem that at run-time a wrong version of the library is loaded. If so, the executable and the library have seen different header files (of the library modules) and all sorts of funny errors occur, usually crashing the code.

I wonder whether there is a simple way to detect this at run time (and produce a useful error message). Of course, I can try to keep the version of the library and compare that from the header files with that from the library -- but how to keep such a version automatically? (I want to minimize human intervention to avoid mistakes and oversights). I currently use svn to version my code, and am running on linux.

What's more, I don't want to be forced (for this to work) to re-compile any executable if a library module has changed.

(note that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24287561/1023390) doesn't help me.)

Comment: What about adding a function GetVersion() and test the result in your application?

Comment: @ViktorLiehr How could that function be implemented and how could it be tested?

Comment: @Walter: Straightforward, just a uint32_t GetVersion() { return 10105; } for v1.01.05 in the Library. And a check in your application code, e.g. LibraryXGetVersion is the function binding to the GetVersion(), So the check is if( LibraryXGetVersion() == 10105) { /* code for correct version */ }

Comment: @ViktorLiehr Of course I thought along those lines, but for that I need an **automatic** way to generate a version for the library interface (or, simpler but equivalent, for each library header file). How to do that?